# Learning Haskell: confusion with reverse function and recursion

Tags: haskell

I've just started to learn Haskell and I am trying to write a simple function that takes a list of strings and reverses each string in the list:

```
revComp :: [String] -> [String]
revComp [] = []
revComp [x] = [] ++ [reverse x]
revComp (x:xs) = revComp [xs]
```

When I try to load my code in GHCI, I get an error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Char' with actual type `[Char]'
Expected type: String
Actual type: [String]
```

Could anyone explain what and where my problem is? Thanks very much.

Comment: Any reason why you didn't do `revComp x = map reverse x` or `revComp = map reverse`?

Comment: He just started learning... @user1255817 map takes a function, and applies it to each element of a list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first three lines are fine. Your type signature is correct, the second line is correct, and so is the third. (However, `[] ++ [reverse x]` is the same as `[reverse x]`.)

The fourth line, however, is wrong. Not only do you not use `x` at all on the right-hand side, but you have a type error: `revComp [xs]` calls `revComp` with a single-element list that has `xs` as its only element. Here, `x` is the first element of the list, and `xs` is the rest of the list. So, since `xs` has the type `[String]`, `[xs]` has the type `[[String]]`, but `revComp` takes a `[String]`! You want to reverse `x`, and prepend that to the result of reversing the rest of the list.

You can use `revComp xs` to reverse each string in the rest of the list, and `(:)` to prepend a value to a list (with the same syntax seen in the `x:xs` pattern you used on the left-hand side). That should be enough information for you to fix the last line. This makes the third line redundant, by the way, since `[x]` is just `x:[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is precisely the help I was looking for.

Comment: Note that String is a synonym for [Char] which explains the type error you got :

Comment: the context "revComp [ _ ]" expects a [Char] in the " _ " spot (because revComp takes a [String]=[[Char]] as argument) but you put xs in this spot and xs was a [String]=[[Char]] since it comes from a pattern match of the argument of revComp. So [xs] type is [[String]]=[[[Char]]]. The actual type in the "_" spot was [[Char]] whereas the type needed (expected) by the context was only [Char]. Expected type : String=[Char], actual type : [String]=[[Char]]. And Char /= [Char], so you get your type error.

Answer (score 6):

ehird's answer is really complete, but I wanted to point out -- as a reference -- the "good/shorter" way to implement that function in real code, since you're new.
It can be defined as the partial application of `map` to `reverse`:

```
Prelude> let revComp = map reverse
Prelude> revComp ["olleh", "dlrow"]
["hello","world"]
```

It results in a function `revComp :: [[a]] -> [[a]]` (and not `[String] -> [String]` since both `map` and `reverse` work on any type of lists) that maps `reverse` to every element of the input list, returning the list of results.

Comment: Thanks, this was quite helpful and obviously a better solution than my attempt.

Answer (score 4):

The third line might not be required even with your example. The edge case (terminating condition) can be only the empty list. You can skip the condition for the single element.

```
revComp :: [String] -> [String]
revComp [] = []
revComp (x:xs) = reverse x : revComp xs
```

Don't know if there is a CS term for this. Someone in the community can add that information.

Answer (score 1):

A few more ways to do the same thing:

```
    revstr [] = []
    revstr (x:xs) = reverse x : revstr xs

    revstr2 [] = []
    revstr2 (x:xs) = [reverse x] ++ revstr2 xs

    revstr3 xs = map reverse xs
    revstr4 = map reverse       -- map takes 2 arguments ;)

    revstr5 xs = foldl step [] xs
     where step acc x = acc ++ [reverse x]

    revstr6 xs = foldr step [] xs
     where step x acc = reverse x : acc
```